# spark streaming Twitter- filter languaje

Tags: scala, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I know that this question has been treated in several posts, but I can't find out how to solve my problem. I am trying to filter twitts by languaje. I have read in this forum that I have to use twitter4j api. I have already added it in my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code is:

```
import twitter4j.api
[....]
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple", "$SPARK_HOME", List("target/streamingTwitter-1.0.jar"))
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
var filter = Array("filter")
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filter).filter(status => _.getLang == "es")
```

The error is:

```
cannot resolve symbol getlang
```

Why the compiler doesnt recognize getLang method? This method is supposed to be implemented in twitter4j api, right? Is not enough to import twitter4j and set dependencies in order to use its methods?

Comment: It might be confused by how you've constructed the filter. Try this instead: `(_.getLang == "es")`

Comment: `status => _.getLang == "es"` This is an anonymous function with a single argument `status` that you then don't use. Either use @Todd's suggestion or `status => _status.getLand == "es"`?

Comment: Thanks to both, i have tried both solutions but none of them work... the eror that throws is the same